# How can I assign a value to a function call?

Tags: python, oop

I try to build a class named "Point" representing 3d-coordinates (x,y,z).

```
class Point(object):

    def __init__(self):
        a = 3
        self.data = [[[bool(False) for x in xrange(a)] for y in xrange(a)] for z in xrange(a)]

    def __call__(self, x, y, z):
       return 'call :'+self.data[x][y][z]'
```

I can easily access a point:

```
p = Point()
print p(1 ,1, 1)   # output : False`
```

BUT, I can't assign a value to this point !

```
p(1, 1, 0) = True  # SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Well what would be the expected behavior? You cannot assign to a call in Python.

Comment: Also you can't concatenate string and bool `'call :'+self.data[x][y][z]`

Comment: Your `Point` is really a **Cube**: it is a 3 x 3 x 3 cube.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you write that, you get the following error:

> `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

Note that this is a **`SyntaxError`** that means that Python does not even bother to **try** to evaluate that. It says: that is **not in the Python grammar**, so it is not supposed to work that way.

A thing that comes a **bit close** to what you ask is **overriding the `__setitem__`** function so that you can assign with `p[1,1,0]` (note that these are square brackets). Like:

```
class Point(object):

    def __init__(self):
        a = 3
        self.data = [[[bool(False) for x in xrange(a)] for y in xrange(a)] for z in xrange(a)]

    def __setitem__(self,idx,val):
        i,j,k = idx
        self.data[i][j][k] = val

    def __call__(self, x, y, z):
       return 'call :'+str(self.data[x][y][z])
```

Now it works like:

```
>>> p = Point()
>>> p(1,1,0)
'call :False'
>>> p[1,1,0] = True # note the square brackets
>>> p(1,1,0)
'call :True'
```

Comment: Thanks, that's fine.

Comment: My only concern would be about the syntax which is not the same for get and set method : p[1,1,0] = True to set value, p(1, 1, 0) to get value... Anyway, thank you for your support !

Comment: @iakoutsk: you can also override `__getitem__` such that you obtain a value with `p[1,1,0]` instead of `p(1,1,0)`...